# Remix-Run Page Transition Animation With Framer Motion

Tags: framer-motion, remix.run

I would like to add some page transitions to my web app.
The problem is that the exit animation doesn't work.

I have a Motion Component

```
// app/components/Motion.tsx    
import React from "react";
import { motion } from "framer-motion";
export default function Motion(props: {
  children: React.ReactChild | React.ReactFragment | React.ReactPortal;
}) {
  return (
    <motion.div
      className="w-full h-screen bg-blue-400 flex pt-24 mx-auto"
      initial={{ opacity: 0, x: -100 }}
      animate={{ opacity: 1, x: 0 }}
      exit={{ opacity: 0, x: -100 }}
      transition={{ duration: 2 }}
    >
      {props.children}
    </motion.div>
  );
}
```

In which I want to wrap every page like this:

```
// app/routes/contact.tsx
import Motion from "~/components/Motion";

export default function contact() {
  return (
    <Motion>
      <div>Contact</div>
    </Motion>
  );
}
```

I know that I should use the `<AnimatePresence>` from framer-motion but I don't know where.

Answer (score 5):

Funny enough, I was just trying to figure out how to do this a few hours ago. I'm super new to Remix, but here's a really simple example of what I did to get route animations working.

1. `root.jsx`

```
import {
  Links,
  LiveReload,
  Meta,
  Outlet,
  Scripts,
  ScrollRestoration,
} from 'remix'

import { AnimatePresence } from 'framer-motion'

import styles from './styles/app.css'

export function meta() {
  return {
    charset: 'utf-8',
    title: 'New Remix App',
    viewport: 'width=device-width,initial-scale=1',
  }
}

export function links() {
  return [{ rel: 'stylesheet', href: styles }]
}

export default function App() {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <Meta />
        <Links />
      </head>
      <body>
        <AnimatePresence exitBeforeEnter>
          <Outlet />
        </AnimatePresence>
        <ScrollRestoration />
        <Scripts />
        <LiveReload />
      </body>
    </html>
  )
}
```

2. Example of first route `index.jsx`

```
import { motion } from 'framer-motion'

export default function Index() {
  return (
        <motion.div
          initial={{ opacity: 0 }}
          animate={{ opacity: 1 }}
          exit={{ opacity: 0 }}
          transition={{ duration: 0.5 }}
          className="w-full h-full md:col-span-3 sm:overflow-auto relative z-0"
        >

               {/* page content */}

        </motion.div>
```

3. Same `<motion.div></motion.div>` parent elements as above to be applied to the next route (e.g. `about.jsx`) - including the same initial, animate, exit, and transition attributes.

Comment: Are you sure that your exit animation is actually working? I have tried wrapping `<Outlet />` in `<AnimatePresence />` exactly as you did, but the exit animation still doesn't work. I assume that I should wrap the deepest component in component tree, which will not be unmounted after changing the Route, in `<AnimatePresence />`. But I still don't know how to do that in Remix.

Comment: Ok after some digging, I think I may have found a possible solution: https://codesandbox.io/s/github/remix-run/remix/tree/main/examples/framer-route-animation?file=/app/root.tsx -- I found this from the following Pull: https://github.com/remix-run/remix/pull/2126/commits/a8c40106c89badad90796677e4975b49d1a809c8

Answer (score 1):

You can try this out at the “root.tsx” file.

```
     <AnimatePresence mode="wait">
      <motion.div
        key={useLocation().pathname}
        variants={{
          initial: { opacity: 0, y: -1000 },
          animate: { opacity: 1, y: 0 },
          exit: { opacity: 1, y: 1000 },
        }}
        initial="initial"
        animate="animate"
        exit="exit"
      >
        <Outlet />
      </motion.div>
```

Please note the “mode” prop instead of exitBeforeEnter (deprecated).

And also notice the key prop in the child.

Hope this helps.

Source: [fixtergeek.com](https://fixtergeek.com/blog/how-to-transition-between-pages-with-framer-motion-and-remix-2023)